# Sync Magento qty with existing POS

Tags: mysql, quantity, pos

We are building a Magento online store for our brick and mortar retail store. We have been running our daily sells with our taylor made in house developed POS system. It stores all information in a MySql database.

Do you know of anything that can help us sync both Magento and POS qty to avoid stock problems. Maybe some kind of trigger that makes Magento qty to update when POS makes a sell and POS qty to update when Magento does.

Any light in the subject will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This question pops up now and then and there are many ways in which you could do it.

A popular method for exporting sales from Magento is to hook in to the sales_order_place_after observer which gets triggered when a sale happens. You could either send the data directly to your POS system or store the data and send it on a cron at a time of your choosing.

Getting data from your POS in to Magento can be done through the Magento API. The API is fairly extensive but can be added to with your own modules if you need it to do something not already coded for.

Comment: For purposes of performance, you may also want to configure your POS to produce a delta update (only update the items that have changed since the last update), as opposed to a full inventory update.